# OL-LI list Numbers in Unicode

Tags: css, unicode, html-lists

I am currently working on a website which has English and Hindi version. Can someone please tell me how can I get the OL - LI numbers in Unicode? So, the numbers in list will also be presented in Hindi glyph than English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring in the [Devanagari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) alphabet, you can use the `list-style-type: devanagari;` property:

Code snippet:

```css
ol{
  list-style-type: devanagari;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `list-style-type` CSS property, use it like this.

```
ol {
  list-style-type:lower-roman;
}
```

In my example I've used roman numerals as I don't know much about hindi, you can have a look at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) (the values section) to determine which value you are looking for.